# Replace few characters in a mulitline string in java

Tags: java, string, replace, str-replace, multiline

Have a multi-line string like below:

```
String str="CreditCardDetails={\n"
           +"CreditCardHolder=\"PJPJ PJPJ\"\n"
           +"CreditCardNumber=\"4111111111111111\"}";
```

Need to change it to something like this in Java:

```
CreditCardDetails={
CreditCardHolder="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
CreditCardNumber="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"}
```

Comment: What is that output, another String?

Comment: Yes need to replace it to the second string

Answer (score 3):

You can just replace quoted content:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\".*?\"", "\"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\"");
```

Which produces the expected string:

```
CreditCardDetails={
CreditCardHolderX2="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
CreditCardNumberX2="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"}
```

Comment: Where regex `.*?` means the shortest sequence `*?` of any char `.`; hence not taking quote chars.